# How to control order when displaying child categories

Tags: categories

I'm working on displaying a series of child categories in the meta of each post. For instance, after the post appears an array, depending on category selection, describing the post content:

Color: Red | Shape: Circle | etc.

The following code displays the content as desires except not in the correct order. The display currently appears as alpha order of the child categories.

I need to either order the categories by parent ID or in the order their presented in the code.

Any ideas?

```
<span class="cat-links">
    <?php
    foreach((get_the_category('orderby=ID&order=ASC')) as $childcat) {
    if (cat_is_ancestor_of(3, $childcat)) {
    echo 'Color: '. '<a href="'.get_category_link($childcat->cat_ID).'">';
 echo $childcat->cat_name . '</a> | ';
    }
    if (cat_is_ancestor_of(10, $childcat)) {
    echo 'Shape: '. '<a href="'.get_category_link($childcat->cat_ID).'">';
 echo $childcat->cat_name . '</a> | ';
    }
    }
    ?>
</span>
```

Comment: "I need to either order the categories by parent ID or in the order their presented in the code." ???

Comment: Yes, the current orderby param is affecting the child. If a post has Color: Blue and Size: Small, Color is listed first and Size next. If a post has Color: Red and Size: Large, then Size is displayed first then Color. The two ways I specified are possibilities that occurred to me. I need to be able to consistently display category order according to the parent, however it's done.

Comment: Ehm... Why don't you just exchange the code blocks?

Comment: I tried that. Same result.

Comment: Do a `var_dump` of the inputs of your `foreach` loop and link to a pastebin.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. `var_dump` is unfamiliar to me, but I dig into it and see how it would work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you install [Category and Taxonomy Terms Order](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/taxonomy-terms-order/) you get a nice drag and drop interface and all you have to do to call it is to set `orderby => 'menu_order'` and you're done, your drag and drop category changes will be instantly reflected in your category order.

Comment: I tried this plugin and it hasn't effected the order of categories in post meta. I add orderby => menu_order to the get_the_category tag, placing the current param, yes?

Comment: Should be `menu_order`...check the documentation, it's pretty good.

Comment: `menu_order`, I figured out. Looks like a helpful plugin. It this situation, though, it's not working. (I checked in a live sandbox and my XAMPP setup.) From what I tell, the param in `get_the_category` is applying to the child since it's getting `as $childcat`.